# How to show a custom View class in a nested layout?

Tags: java, android

I have made a custom class extending from View `public class MyView extends View` which draws a math function. I want it to be drawn in activity with two/nested (don't know which term is more accurate) layouts.

I know how to show it in simple empty activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(myView(this)); //draws function on entire screen
   }
}
```

But to show it in activity which XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
  <ConstraintLayout>

    //draw my function here

  </ConstraintLayout>
  <ConstraintLayout>
  </ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea :( Or maybe my approach is all wrong? Please help

As to **Eixx's** answer, Im getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc/com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc.DrawFuncActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc.Func
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc.Func
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc.Func
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:618)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.pwtafunc.marko.pwtafunc.DrawFuncActivity.onCreate(DrawFuncActivity.java:16)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

As to what **Kling Klang** wrote, sorry my mistake, it was `NullPointerException`, but when I dealt with the function is drawn on the entire screen anyway :(

And **Marcin Grabowski** solution is the right one, thank You very much.

Comment: Use it **normally**. It doesn't actually matter, if it's nested or not.

Comment: Why the down vote ? 
If I will do it like this `setContentView(myView(this));` in activity with nested layout, app keeps crashing :(

Comment: Post the full logcat. Let's bet you have a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also add it from code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_constraint_layout_id);
        constraintLayout.addView(myView(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just insert it into the XML, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
  <ConstraintLayout>

    <com.example.MyView/>

  </ConstraintLayout>
  <ConstraintLayout>
  </ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

plus to Eixx's answer.

To allow your view be used in XML layout file directly, you will need to at least implement constructor

```
    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```